# moving a robot inside specific area

Tags: navigation, base-global-planner, nav-msgs, rosaria, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a pioneer robot and I want to move it in the lab and I want to keep it in a square area. So when ever it want to cross that area it cant. I dont want to send a zero velocity to it so it will stuck in the boundry of the square.

Using the odom of the robot the start position is (0,0). I want the sqaure area is 2 by 2 and the pioneer starts from a corner or in the middle.
When it reah the boundry it can rotate to inside direction of the square do it can move forward and backword.

The pioneer has topic RosAria/pose which is from type nav_msgs/Odometry ...

any suggestions or a code some one wrote for this

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201045/moving-a-robot-inside-specific-area/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot is controlled by specifying desired velocity (translation and rotation) of the robot by publishing desired velocity to `RosAria/cmd_vel` (from a client, or for testing, from 'rostopic'), which you can change at any time.  Do this while monitoring `pose` (and, eventually, sensor data as well) and you can make the robot move in a certain trajectory or pattern over time.   You can start with basic proportional control and a state machine.  As you approach the edge of the square, slow the robot down until stopped. Then turn (new state).  When done turning, begin moving again.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-03-06**:
Hi I am trying to move my Powerbot using RosAria and by following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals). So far, although the goal seems to be "sent", the robot does not move. Does this have to do with the fact that I'm using RosAria? What can I do?